# JSTL SQL Basics

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jstl, scriptlet

Does anyone have good reference which can help me understand JSTL SQL Basics
I have already gone through
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_database_access.htm

But needed something which explains in detail how the syntax and how the mapping actually works for JSTL SQL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just consult [its own tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnald.html).

Please note that the use of this taglib is **discouraged** for production use. It's intented for quick prototyping. Here's a cite straight from the 1st paragraph of the linked tutorial:

> The JSTL SQL tags for accessing databases listed in Table 7-7 are designed for quick prototyping and simple applications. For production applications, database operations are normally encapsulated in JavaBeans components.

As to how it's "normally" to be done, you may find [this tutorial](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2008/07/dao-tutorial-data-layer.html) useful as a kickoff point.

---

**Unrelated** to the problem, I'm not sure why you tagged `scriptlet` on your question. JSTL and other taglibs must not to be confused with *scriptlets*. But I just want to make clear that using *scriptlets* is more than discouraged. For more detail, see [How to avoid Java code in JSP files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files)